# Find finalizer thread in dotnet core

Tags: debugging, .net-core, garbage-collection

Analyzing a core dump with dotnet-core it shows there are a lot of objects ready for finalization that are piling up.

Unfortunately the command `threads` does not tell you which thread is the finalizer thread. How can I know?